# Manual and systematic process modeling in bpmn2

Tags: camunda, bpmn, business-process-management

I model a process where most of the process is done in an electronic system, but at one stage, the expert has to write a letter that is outside the system. If I put the pool title as system mail, because sending mail is outside the system, I think the modeling will not be correct.
Also, if I name the pool as a process, all the flows in Camunda software are defined as sequence flow, if the mail is sent outside the system, it should be as message flow. If any of your friends know how a role can do both system work and manual work (in a pool), please write the answer to this question. Thank you

I checked camunda software